# regarding train-test split of data in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark scala data frame like this

```
    val df = Seq(
  (10, 12),
  (44, 14),
  (32, 25),
  (31, 24),
  (75, 25),
  (80, 20),
  (35, 55),
  (32, 25),
  (67, 72),
  (32, 21)
).toDF("x1","x2")

df.show()

+---+---+
| x1| x2|
+---+---+
| 10| 12|
| 44| 14|
| 32| 25|
| 31| 24|
| 75| 25|
| 80| 20|
| 35| 55|
| 32| 25|
| 67| 72|
| 32| 21|
+---+---+
```

I need to split this data as training and testing where training data would be the first 8 rows (80%) and testing data would be the last 2 rows (20%).

I tried , `val Array(train, test) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))` But it is select 8 rows randomly (instead of choosing first 8 rows) as training and others as testing

So can anyone suggest how to select the partitions as i mentioned above ?

Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you prefer to split based on order rather than randomly?

Comment: @ernest_k my actual data set is a time series data set. In that case i cannot randomly split the data.

Comment: randomSplit randomly splits a RDD with the provided weights. there is no way with randomsplit atleast

Comment: you can split with manual coding may be you can introduce index column and total count of rows based on the index you can do a percentage selection i thinl try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way but nothing else comes to my mind as you require data to be ordered.

```
val cnt = df.count
val testSize = (0.2 * cnt).toInt
val trainSize = cnt - testSize

val trainDf = df.sort(monotonically_increasing_id).limit(trainSize)
val testDf = df.sort(monotonically_increasing_id.desc).limit(testSize)
```